Permission To create New Folder
I use the GParted to create a new Partition.





And, I activate it through the Disks.





However, the newly created disk does not allow me to create new folders.





What's more, I cannot even create new folders through the command window.





Please tell me how to get the permission to create new folders.

Please read the info on this link. After edit the question and add some actual details As written there is nothing here to help you with. All you have is a list of links that do not work. https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask
